# If category is not active, then and products set no active Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have Model category with global Scope:

```
 /**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('active', true);
    });
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Model product:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('active', true);
    });
}
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

I need do, if category is not active, then set and products in this category is not active. How I can do this?

Now when category is not active, products can be showed on page. I can in model product add global scope of active category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Product Model):

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('active', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder
                ->where('active', true)
                ->whereHas('category', function($query){
                    $query->where('active', true);
                });
    });
}
```